# collapsing series of spaces

Tags: c#, refactoring

Refactoring existing code.

They are trying to collapse any series of spaces in string passed in to a single space.

Surely there is a better way.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            str = str.Replace("  ", " ");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str,@"\s+"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using

```
List<string> spiltList = yourStr.Split(' ').ToList();
```

Remove empty string from collection.

```
spiltList.RemoveAll(e => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e));
```

Join the list of strings to a single string

```
string result = string.Join(" ", spiltList);
```

Comment: None of this code will compile.  First off there is no static `Split` method on `String`.  I assume you meant something like `yourString.Split(" ");`.  Second there is no overload of `string.Split` that takes a single string.  You can pass a single `char` or an array of strings and a `StringSplitOptions`.  Speaking of which you can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to remove the empties.  Second array does not have a `remove` method and if it did you'd want to remove empty strings not a one space string.  Finally it's `string.Join`.

Comment: So I believe the answer you were going for is `str = string.Join(" ", str.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`